# How can I keep date format of a nested document in spring data elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to create a document B that is composed of another document A and I want to keep the same date format used for A date fields instead of a long value.

spring-boot version: 2.4.3

A.java

```
@Document(indexName = "a_index")
@Data
public class A {
    private Long id;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.date_time)
    private LocalDateTime date;

}
```

B.java

```
@Document(indexName = "b_index")
@Data
public class B {
    private Long id;
    private A a;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `@Field` annotation to the property of `B`:

```java
    @Document(indexName = "b_index")
    @Data
    public class B {
        private Long id;
        @Field(type= FieldType.Object)
        private A a;
    
    }
```

When Spring Data Elasticsearch writes the index mapping on index creation, only properties that are annotated with `@Field` are considered. That means as well that after changing the code you need to have Spring Data Elasticsearch recreate the mapping.

Different topic: why do you have a `@Document` annotation o the `A` class? Do you write `A` data to the *a_index* **and** as embedded objects to the *b_index*?